# How to pattern match first occurence?

Tags: java, matcher

How can I always take the first element matched by a pattern?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)K");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("CARRY8K");
baggageWeight = matcher.group(); //I'd like to extract the "8"
```

Result: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`

Why?

Comment: By "extract", do you mean "remove" from the string, or do you want to set a variable to it, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`matcher.group()` throws `IllegalStateException` If no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed. Here you haven't used `find()` which attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you do like this you extract "8" from the String "CARRY8K"

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)K");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("CARRY8K");
if (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using String.indexOf(string) to find the location of the string within the main string. Using indexOf you can then extract the value at the specified index. For example:

```
String s = "CARRY8K";
int index = s.indexOf("8");
```

"index" will be set to the location of the first instance of the specified character. In this case, "8". You can then use the index to perform other operations--either to print the location of the character, or remove it from your main string.

If you want to remove it, just use a stringbuilder and the setCharAt() method:

```
StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(s);
newString.setCharAt(index, '');
```

This will replace the character at the specified index to a blank, effectively removing it from the main string.

Comment: You did not say you wanted to extract an unknown number. Next time I suggest making your question clearer so it's easier to understand what you were looking for.